# editText.setOnEditorActionListener error on developer.android.com

Tags: java, android

I see this code on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html) for handle the IME_ACTION of the softkeyboard:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

If you see, this code not working because the mehod OnEditorActionListener is for a TextView type...

So, what are the right method to haddling the IME_ACTION of the softkeyboard?

Comment: An [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) *is* a `TextView`.

Comment: That is the right method for handling ime action and I am using it in one of my apps

Comment: @Pang edittext inherits textview but is not a textview

Comment: @IllegalArgument Well... you're right. `EditText extends TextView`.

Comment: @IllegalArgument can you show me that piece of code, I'm lost I can't make it work. My code is the same as the example, and is in onResume and has in just a Log.e(); but nothing happend...

Comment: @wwwanaya Try `Log.e()` outside the `if` and see what happens? And one more `Log.e()` in `onResume()` too, just in case.

Comment: are you using findViewById declaring edittext variable and using above code all in the onresume method??

Comment: not working... how, exactly? crashing? not doing anything?

Comment: Is done IllegalArgument and matiash, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please use ButterKnife instead

```
@OnEditorAction(R.id.editText)
protected boolean actionDo(int actionId){
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        doCalculate();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify imeOption prior to responding action

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

And then you can respond to it by using following code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should alwasy return false to onEditorAction method.